# UWP Unit Test Project Clearing local setting values

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have a UWP application and a unit test project within the Solution. When I try to run the unit test project in the debugging mode, the data I have stored in the local settings for the app gets cleared.

I will get the local setting like below.

```
var localSettings= Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";
```

I will set the value for "exampleSetting" when I run the app. Now I will close the app and then when I run the unit test project and try to access "exampleSetting" the value is null.

Comment: Your question is unclear to follow when "Hello Windows" is defined and when it's checked.

Comment: Have edited the question. Can u get my point now.

Comment: did you mean, you are about to access app data from unittest project? unit test project and your app project use _different_ app data location.

Comment: yes u got my point. But if I want to test a Method that access the local setting of the app, how can I unit test that method?

Comment: The unit test code should be designed in _unit_. Your value setting is one of unit, and your value reading is another unit. Try to redesign your test code by separating reading/setting value. This could be out of scope of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content was too huge to be put in a comment so i'll post it as an answer instead.

If the code provided by you is the only piece of code you write to add the value to the storage then, you're missing out the last line of code where you update your local settings. Your updated code would look something like below:

```
var localSettings= Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings = localSettings;
```

The last line would update the existing local settings to the modified ones.

Now Coming to local storage testing, the testing is done in a testing environment so the test would not be able to store or retain values outside the environment so, when you store data to local storage of the app in a unit test, it will not be reflected when the app runs and vis.ver. I say this because I faced the same issue while using `NUnitTests` for my UWP app.

Comment: Do you know of any way of stopping the unit tests from clearing the local settings? I am syncing a 15 meg SQLite database in to my local settings which takes some time, and I need to execute some tests against the database. It's going to make it impossible to do fast unit testing if I have to sync the whole database every single time.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper Honestly I would recommend Mocking your Services that interact with your SQLite DB. And once you're ready with Unit Tests & Component Tests, handle the SQLite test cases in Integration Testing. There is no way, (at least that I am aware of) that'll help you retain your SQLiteDB changes that are done during the UnitTests. That being said if, If one Test depends on another for some data, that's a hint to mock.

Comment: Most people say that. But, I need to test the data layer. So, mocking up tests just skips around the bits I need to test.

Comment: What I've done for now is to copy the database in to the local storage right at the point where the unit test (or integration test if you will) needs it. This is a big hack. Not sure why UWP unit testing automatically assumes that the only way you would want to test would be in a clean state when actually you should be testing in clean and dirty states.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper yeah I wasn't aware of the fact that you were testing your Data-Layer. To get started [refer this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite). Notice the `new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:")` from the docs. this is what is triggering the behavior to run from clean slate